# How to make images look sharp

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying my app on a Samsung tab 2 (10.1) and it is supposed to have a resolution of 1200x800. My images take up about 75% of the screen, but even if I create them with the size of 1280*800 with 320 dpi they still look kind of blurry.

However if I create them even larger, for example 2000 in height (it's a portrait app), they look sharp. Why do they have to be that large in size? What am I missing?

I'm sure others have had this issue but I couldn't find a good solution by searching.

Thanks.

/Nick

Comment: You should probably have a slightly more descriptive title... in any case, the couple things I would check is: (1) the actual screen density, (2) the `scaleType` if you are putting it in an `ImageView`, (3) your image should genuinely be 320 dpi not just open in Photoshop and set it's density to 320 dpi, and (4) make sure the image is put in the appropriate density image resource folder (ie. `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, etc.)

Comment: Ok the title could have been better. 1) The actual screen density is 149 ppi. 2) scaleType is fitCenter 3) How do I do 'genuinely' 320 dpi in photoshop? 4) The images are located in xhdpi (only - for now).